# how to get rid of empty cells while doing column grouping in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, mdx

I have added a column group in my report, which should work as below.

group1 group2 group3
data1  data1  data1

But my results page looks like this

group1  group2  group3
data1    null   null
null    data1 null
        null  null  data1

how do i get rid of nulls or empty spaces above?
please help me how do i fix this issue.
FYI, data1 is not a single column. under each column group, i have 7,8 columns that needs to show/repeat for each column group.

Appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Comment: What's the underlying `MDX`?

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a SUM row on your detail group.  Then delete the Detail group leaving the SUM row.  It will then display the data correctly.